# Derivative of adjoint operator-valued function

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Consider an infinite dimensional complex Hilbert space $H$. I think that for a bounded operator-valued function $A: x\mapsto A(x) \in \mathcal B(H)$, where $x\in \mathbb R$, we can define the derivative $A^\prime(x)$ as the (unique) operator which obeys

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \left\|A^\prime(x) - \tfrac{A(x+h)-A(x)}{h}\right\|_{\mathrm{op}} =0 \quad, \tag 1$$

if the limit exists. Here $\|\cdot\|_{\mathrm{op}}$ denotes the operator norm.

Now I think that from $\|A(x)^*\|_{\mathrm{op}}=\|A(x)\|_{\mathrm{op}}$, where $^*$ denotes the adjoint, we can show that the derivative of $A^*: x\mapsto A(x)^*$ exists at $x$ and is simply the adjoint of the derivative of $A$ at $x$, i.e we have
$$ (A^\prime(x))^* = (A^*)^\prime (x) \quad .\tag{2}$$

**Question:**

Can we find the same result as in $(2)$ if we define the derivative of bounded operator-valued functions in the strong operator topology instead of the uniform topology $(1)$? Or is there a weaker but similar result under some conditions?

Comment: You can get proper double norm bars by using `\|` instead of `||`.

Comment: This is a very subtle question!!!! Yes, seeing that the "strong" (as opposed to "uniform") operator topology is probably relevant for unbounded operators is (in my opinion) a very useful point.

Comment: @joriki Thanks, noted!

Comment: Dear @paulgarrett , thanks your your comment. Yes, but also in the case of a bounded operator-valued function this can make a difference; what I mean mean is that one could also define the derivative in terms of the SOT for bounded operator-valued functions; then their derivatives (if existent in the SOT) must not be bounded operators anymore. And so the derivative in the SOT might exist in cases where it does not exist for the uniform topology, which is important in the context of quantum mechanics, which also is the context where this question came up.

Comment: @Jakob, Aha! I was not aware of the significance of derivatives that exist in SOT but not in uniform! In my own business, repn theory and automorphic forms..., often integrals of operators converge in the SOT, but not the uniform...

Comment: @paulgarrett At least this is what I've understood so far. In other words, I think that if the derivative exists in the uniform sense (and is thus a bounded operator), then it exists in the SOT sense with the same derivative; however, if the derivative in the SOT exists, it might not exist in the uniform sense and in particular, it can happen to be an unbounded operator, cf. [Stone's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups). This is very important in quantum mechanics, as it is the basis for the time-evolution of quantum systems.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer for an admittedly very restrictive special case.

To start, consider the following subspace:
$$\mathcal D(A^\prime(x)):=\left\{\psi\in H\,|\, \exists\, \psi_x \in H\, : \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\,\left\|\psi_x-\tfrac{A(x+h)-A(x)}{h}\psi \right\|=0\right\} \quad . $$

We find that for each $\psi \in \mathcal D(A^\prime(x))$, the corresponding $\psi_x$ is unique and this in turn allows us to define an operator $A^\prime(x): \mathcal D(A^\prime(x)) \longrightarrow H$ as $$A^\prime(x)\psi:=\psi_x$$
and extend by linearity. It is a well-defined linear operator and we call it the derivative of $A$ at $x$.$^1$

Now assume that $\mathcal D(A^\prime(x))=H$. I think that from the [uniform boundedness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle#Corollaries) it then follows that $A^\prime(x)$ is bounded$^2$, which in turn implies that $(A^\prime(x))^*$ is bounded and defined on the whole Hilbert space as well. With that we can show that $A^*: x\mapsto A(x)^*$ is differentiable in the *weak* sense and its derivative is $(A^\prime(x))^*$.

Indeed, by making use of the continuity of the underlying inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle: H\times H \longrightarrow \mathbb C$, we find for all $\phi,\psi \in H$:
\begin{align}
\left\langle (A^\prime(x))^*\phi,\psi\right\rangle &= \langle \phi,A^\prime(x) \psi\rangle \\
&= \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\, \left\langle \phi,\tfrac{A(x+h)-A(x)}{h}\psi\right\rangle  \\
&= \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\, \left\langle \left(\tfrac{A(x+h)-A(x)}{h}\right)^* \phi,\psi\right\rangle \\
&= \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\left\langle \tfrac{A^*(x+h)-A^*(x)}{h}\phi,\psi\right\rangle \quad .
\end{align}

---

$^1$ I think this resembles the notion given [here](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Inequivalent_Representations_of_Canonica/up_ODwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Inequivalent+Representations+of+Canonical+Commutation+and+Anti-Commutation+Relations&printsec=frontcover), p. 20-21.

$^2$ Thanks to @V. Moretti for pointing that out.